# C++: move or assign

Tags: c++

I have the following function

```
template<typename OutClass,typename InClass>
OutClass & move_or_assign(InClass & IC){
    if(std::is_base_of<OutClass,InClass>::value)
        return std::move(IC);
    return IC;
}
```

This function compiles, and my class has an assignment operator overload such that assignment between instantiations performs a type conversion:

```
typeA<typeX> ax;

void function(typeA<typeX> & ax){
    typeA<typeY> ay = ax; // <-- works
}
```

Ideally, I write:

```
template<typename I>
void function(typeA<I> & ax){
   typeA<typeY> ay = move_or_assign(ax);
}
// such that ay is only "assigned" (which performs a deep copy)
// if I == typeX, but not if I == typeY
```

However, when I call it, the compiler complains as follows:

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 
'A::typeY&' from an rvalue of 
type 'std::remove_reference<A::typeX&>::type {aka A::typeX}'

@ line:
if(std::is_base_of<OutClass,InClass>()) return std::move(IC);
```

Not sure how to perform this operation, but it seems like it should be possible?

---

An example of a situation where I would write everything out:

I have a data structure that works in two orientations. I need to loop through the data structure in one orientation or another. However, I need to avoid unnecessary conversions, as it is large, so I need to check which orientation it is in:

```
enum orientation {left,right}
struct Left{};
struct Right{};
template<class Dir>
struct DataStruct{};

template<typename data>
void function(data d,orientation dir){

    if(dir == left){
        if(std::is_base_of<data,DataStruct<Left>>::value){
            Data<Right> dr = d;
            loop_through(d,dr,some_func);
        }
        else loop_through(d,d,some_func);
    } else {
        // etc.
    }
}
```

And I have come up with this `light_copy_or_assign` function to replace the inner if statements:

```
// rather than: 
if(std::is_base_of<data,DataStruct<Left>>::value){
    Data<Right> dr = d;
    loop_through(d,dr,some_func);
}
else loop_through(d,d,some_func);

// I would write: 
Data<Right> dr = light_copy_or_assign(d);
loop_through(d,dr,some_func);
```

Comment: No, it's not possible. Even if it were possible, `std::move` returns, in effect, a temporary object, which will be destroyed when its scope terminates, which will be immediate, since you're returning from that scope. Even if it were possible, you will end up returning a reference to a destroyed object, and using it will result in undefined behavior. C++ will not let you do this, for your own good.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik so there is no way to eliminate repetitive if statements that abound when dealing with fundamental high performance types that must be converted between forms routinely?  There must be a way...

Comment: I don't know anything about "repetitive if" statements, just pointing out why you can't turn the result of a `std::move` into a mutable reference. Sounds to me like your `move_or_assign` should take a reference to both objects, and use the appropriate logic, accordingly. Furthermore, you may need to specialize your template, or perhaps use `constexpr if`, since even if `if()` evaluates to a constant false value, the code inside the `if` statement must be valid C++, and won't just disappear into a puff of air, even if it gets optimized away.

Comment: Can you give an example of the situations where you are having to write this out by hand?

Comment: @AlanStokes yeah, one sec

Comment: Your return type is wrong for the move case (and indeed the copy case) so you're definitely going to have to have two overloads and use metaprogramming to select the correct one.

Comment: @AlanStokes alright, posted the example.  Note that the `DataStruct` is a third party library class. I can wrap it, but I am wary of doing that.

Comment: `move_or_assign` can’t deduce its `OutClass` template parameter.  Why don’t you just always call `std::move`?  The resulting xvalue can still bind to `const T&` if needed.